# Is mingw-w64 silently changing fopen64() to fopen()?

Tags: mingw, large-files

I'm trying to track down some undefined behavior in a piece of code I am writing which requires large file support. To that end I have been using the `fopen64()` family of functions. I can across this delightful little code snippet in the mingw-w64 source:

https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/fopen64.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE* fopen64 (const char* filename, const char* mode)
{
    return fopen (filename, mode);
}
```

It seems straightforward but I'm still a little in disbelief. Is mingw64 really silently and without warning defaulting to removing large file support? Or is there more to this that I am missing?